# Drop Databricks table if older than 30 days

Tags: databricks

I would like to drop Databricks SQL DB tables, if the table was created more than 30 days ago. How do I get the table created datetime from databricks?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Given a `tableName`, the easiest way to get the creation time is as follows:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.TableIdentifier

val createdAtMillis = spark.sessionState.catalog
  .getTempViewOrPermanentTableMetadata(new TableIdentifier(tableName))
  .createTime
```

`getTempViewOrPermanentTableMetadata()` returns `CatalogTable` that contains information such as:

```
CatalogTable(
Database: default
Table: dimension_npi
Owner: root
Created Time: Fri Jan 10 23:37:18 UTC 2020
Last Access: Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 UTC 1970
Created By: Spark 2.4.4
Type: MANAGED
Provider: parquet
Num Buckets: 8
Bucket Columns: [`npi`]
Sort Columns: [`npi`]
Table Properties: [transient_lastDdlTime=1578699438]
Location: dbfs:/user/hive/warehouse/dimension_npi
Serde Library: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe
InputFormat: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileInputFormat
OutputFormat: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveSequenceFileOutputFormat
Schema: root
 |-- npi: integer (nullable = true)
 ...
)
```

You can list all tables in a database using `sessionCatalog.listTables(database)`.

There are alternative ways of accomplishing the same but with a lot more effort and risking errors due to Spark behavior changes: poking about table metadata using SQL and/or traversing the locations where tables are stored and looking at file timestamps. That's why it's best to go via the catalog APIs.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your DB table is delta:

You can use the `DESCRIBE HISTORY <database>.<table>` to retrieve all transactions made to that table, including timestamps. According to the [databricks documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/describe-table.html) - history is only retained for 30 days. Depending on how you plan to implement your solution that may just work.

Comment: `DESCRIBE HISTORY` only applies to Delta tables, it's not available for non-Delta managed tables, which the question is about.

Comment: @Sim The question doesn't actually specify if the table is delta or not. I will update my answer though, thank you.